# Ransack not works on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have restart the server after bundlen install

My env

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

If I remove the search function in book.rb
it show me

```
undefined method `*' for Ransack::Search<class: Book, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

if I add the search function in book.rb

it shows me

```
undefined method `result' for #<Array:0x007f9fa40327d0>
```

index.html

```
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all

    @search = Book.search(params[:q])
    puts @search*50
    @books = @search.result
    puts @search.methods


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @carts }
    end
  end
```

book.rb

```
   def self.search(isbn)

      if isbn
        find(:all, :conditions => ['isbn=?', "#{isbn}"])
      else
        find(:all)
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

`puts @search*50` it's strange.
`Ransack::Search` has no method '*'.
If u want to display search results 50-times:

```
@search = Book.search(params[:q])
@books = @search.result
puts @books*50
```

If you want to use ransack you dont need `def self.search` method in Book model. Just in controller:

```
@search = Book.search(params[:q])
@books = @search.result
```

Comment: I just want to print @books for debug in 50TIMES for easy see it

Comment: actually, after change to your method , i got the same error. NoMethodError in CartsController#index

undefined method `result' for #<Array:0x007fa35f91e718>

Comment: Be sure to remove `self.search` method from Book model.